# Create an dyanamic list from a List(of Class) with where condition

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a class named UserDetail. I have Userstatus field in the userdetail class and created a List(Of UserDetail).

```
Dim UserList As New List(Of UserDetail)()

UserList.Add(New UserDetail() With {.UserId = 1, .UserName = 'ABC', .Status= 0 })
UserList.Add(New UserDetail() With {.UserId = 2, .UserName = 'CFC', .Status= 2 })
UserList.Add(New UserDetail() With {.UserId = 3, .UserName = 'AAC', .Status= 2 })
```

I want to iterate all the userdetail from the List and get all with status = 1 to a new list wihch contains only UserID.

How can i do this with Minimum steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *linq* to apply the filter using `.Where` and get list of `UserId` using `.Select`

C# syntax

```
var result = UserList.Where(u=>u.status == 1).Select(u=>u.UserId);
```

VB syntax

```
Dim result = From user In UserList
               Where UserList.status = 1 
               Select user.UserId
```

This MSDN article [Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) will help you learn LinQ using VB.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to iterate your list of users:

```
For Each user As var In UserList.Where(Function(u) u.Status = 1)
    ...
Next
```